Soundminer plus V5 "some files weren't found on disk"
Has anyone had this problem with soundminer?
I can't export files from a certain drive because it gives me this error.
I can however reveal the selected file and it points exactly where it is on the disk,
I just can't drag and drop it out of the software.
Tried reindexing the files, reinstalling, deleting registries after reinstalling, changing the folder's security settings, reseting soundminer's settings folder. Did anything I could think of. The only thing that solves it is moving the files to another drive.
Anyone?
